# IIS 7 sending me to the default web page sometimes

Tags: browser, http, iis

I am working on setting up a IIS server (Windows 2008 R2) and just when I think I have it working, I hit refresh on my browser and it brings me to the default web page (the IIS splash page) instead of going to the website that I am trying to go to.

I have checked on the site bindings and they appear to be correct, I have checked the packets that are being received by the web server and they are receiving the HTTP GET header for the website.  I am at a loss as to why my web server would work for a while, then all of a sudden send me back to the default web page.  Do I have to make the site binding for the default page something crazy?  Delete the default page?  Is there some way I can confirm that the HTTP GET header isn't malformed?  Any input would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: does you site use session state (for ASP.NEt)? if so check this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: I think it is classic ASP for this particular site.  Is there any chance that the web server is having problems resolving the hostname for the web site?

Comment: I have similar issue. There are bindings for specific names on one site and all of them are polled once in 10 minutes. Sometimes IIS replies with content from default site instead of specific one and for the next request it replies correctly again. To narrow down the issue: it's IIS8 on windows 2012 R2, bindings are https and there are 1000+ of them which I suspect can make IIS a bit crazy. Did you have any luck resolving your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found the answer, but I would like for someone to back this one up if they can.

The problem may have been in the fact that my web servers could not resolve the site name that I was trying to navigate to from my workstation.  The reason it could not resolve the site name was because I didn't set up a name resolution in the DNS server and was relying on modifying hosts files to get the resolution done.  The site that was testing exists in production and my web server may have been trying to communicate with that host instead of itself.  I guess this is a problem of not understanding how IIS works and the HTTP protocol.